# How do I properly use code in joomla articles?

Tags: php, javascript, database, joomla

I am very new to web development and CMSs. I want to make a Joomla site that features articles with a lot of graphs at the top of the page and written content below them. The charts will probably be done with fusioncharts and some controls directly below them to dynamically influence the data displayed in the charts preferably without reloading the page.

My question is what is the most appropriate way to do this in joomla? Can I get the sourcer add in and simple create articles using inline javascript calls to place the charts and controls directly in the article? Is this how people usually embed non text based content in joomla? Is it possible to access the database with code directly embedded in the article to generate the chart?

I dont really want to learn too much of the joomla API right now, I'm more interested in using the CMS features to create the pages and then just coding everything else in javascript/php directly in the page but I'm not sure if that is appropriate or if it would introduce security concerns to my site.

Comment: That last paragraph contradicts the **properly** qualifier in your question :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why not try the [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/joomla/) extension for Joomla -

This will be much easier than coding this yourself, the work has already been done.

Comment: The extension is only for the free version, I am just interested in implementing the paid version.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong here but if you want to change to the paid version you just need the paid version flash file? Then you replace the existing flash file with this paid version flash file. What is the difference between the free version of FusionCharts and the paid version - only a watermark?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the best thing to do is just use a good WSIWYG and then use the source code feature.

TinyMCE does the work just fine.

Are you looking for plugins or components to add and do this or do you just want to log into administrator and start doing this right away?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).